# How can i see all videos in a youtube channel?

Tags: youtube, channel

I want to get all videos in a YouTube channel. Is there any way to do that? Can be with pagination, but I can't see any pagination (can't use ajax). I can get urls with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Developers Guide | Videos uploaded by a specific user](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Retrieving_Uploads).

For example the following code retrieves the list of videos uploaded by $userName. You have to [page through the results](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Pagination).

```
function getAndPrintUserUploads($userName)                    
{     
  $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
  $yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
  printVideoFeed($yt->getuserUploads($userName));
}
```

Comment: This will return only 20 results by default. To return different number of results use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2453808).